# How to read data from local txt file in python live plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

In this code, I don't want to write data in code side. How can I read the data from `sample.txt`. For example I deleted `year`, `unemployment`, `deficit` data set on code and I added in txt file. But I couldnt get data from txt file.

tried a few sample code (not worked):

```
year=open('sample.txt','r').read()
unemployment=open('sample.txt','r').read()
deficit=open('sample.txt','r').read()
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

year = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
unemployment = [10.0, 9.5, 8.8, 7.8, 7.2, 5.8]
deficit = [12.8, 12.2, 10.7, 9.3, 6.4, 5.8]


plt.plot(year, unemployment, color='r', marker='o', linestyle='--',
         linewidth = 2.0, label='unemployment')
plt.plot(year, deficit, color='b', marker='o', linestyle='--',
         linewidth = 2.0, label='deficit (%GDP)')

plt.title('sdfsdfsdf')
plt.xlabel('x one')
plt.ylabel('y one')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Sample.txt:

```
1 , 10.0 , 12.8
2 , 9.5 , 12.2
3 , 8.8 , 10.7
4 , 7.8 , 9.3
5 , 7.2 , 6.4
6 , 5.8 , 5.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the format of the `.txt` file, there are at least two options:

1. use Python's built-in [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html).
2. use the numpy's [`loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) functionality.

Given that you are already using the `numpy` library, I would recommend the latter option, it is cleaner and simpler.

---

Modified code (assume `sample.txt` is the name of the file that contains comma seperated data):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

year, unemployment, deficit = np.loadtxt("sample.txt", delimiter=",").transpose()

plt.plot(year, unemployment, color='r', marker='o', linestyle='--',
        linewidth = 2.0, label='unemployment')
plt.plot(year, deficit, color='b', marker='o', linestyle='--',
        linewidth = 2.0, label='deficit (%GDP)')

plt.title('sdfsdfsdf')
plt.xlabel('x one')
plt.ylabel('y one')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

The produced plot is
[image: output of the program]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
year = list()
unemployment = list()
deficit = list()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        strlist = line.strip().split(',')
        year.append(int(strlist[0]))
        unemployment.append(float(strlist[1]))
        deficit.append(float(strlist[2]))
```

With your matplotlib code, it produces,

[image]

Comment: Its also true and useful for me.But I had to choose one of them :(

Comment: @DySt, no worries.